# Android Studio Android Projekt run stand alone Java

Tags: java, android

Hi I programmed an Android app, but some parts of the app contain native Desktop-Java Code which is supposed to run on the Desktop, right now I can just run it within Android Studio and it works, the Android libraries are provided as "stubs", but I want to export it and make it runnable without android studio. But I don't have the slightest idea where to begin. I don't want to create a Java module, because this destroyed my app several times. Any Idea? I know it's bad design to mix Desktop-Java with Android but I need almost all the Desktop-Java code for the Android-App anyways.

Just copied the run line into the windows-cmd and it works even without Android studio but I don't think this will run in any other run-time environment except for my Pc.

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=55051 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\tw\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar;C:\Users\tw\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-26\data\res;F:\zwei18\blubberme\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug;F:\zwei18\blubberme\app\build\generated\res\rs\debug;F:\zwei18\blubberme\app\build\generated\res\resValues\debug;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\animated-vector-drawable-26.0.0.aar\b4b915afcc06edc72907953989a6a029\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\support-annotations\26.0.0\db09a97f4f0db8892c1a0111a4b966f97920d082\support-annotations-26.0.0.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\transition-26.0.0.aar\2216ab7388ea55822f0426346701ad90\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\transition-26.0.0.aar\2216ab7388ea55822f0426346701ad90\res;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.0.0.aar\b621d0ffa5f7edf4f78d6d69c706bedb\res;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.0.0.aar\b621d0ffa5f7edf4f78d6d69c706bedb\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\multidex-1.0.1.aar\73331bbce451c5905e18bb668d168a8a\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-fragment-26.0.0.aar\6cc4503602a68fc2387dc2bb33451a65\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-26.0.0.aar\a2a3417028259290b6250bb82e1eef66\res;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-26.0.0.aar\a2a3417028259290b6250bb82e1eef66\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-1.1.3.aar\a8e8a3da9d5281847b733c2283a691f2\res;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-1.1.3.aar\a8e8a3da9d5281847b733c2283a691f2\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.0.0.aar\9a143a52b1b5faf3d74042078d3bb91b\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.0.0.aar\9a143a52b1b5faf3d74042078d3bb91b\res;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-v4-26.0.0.aar\13c2be756832554a53d9af310221de3e\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-26.0.0.aar\6fc1ad2c887486268d973e3de820567f\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-utils-26.0.0.aar\e4079133536e59e184d0ec91ca10bdb0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-vector-drawable-26.0.0.aar\f003cfe0156b60b8e5a69079c81066d9\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-26.0.0.aar\805dec2c6983e4269fe7d92ec69e5bc8\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-26.0.0.aar\805dec2c6983e4269fe7d92ec69e5bc8\res;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support.constraint\constraint-layout-solver\1.1.3\bde0667d7414c16ed62d3cfe993cff7f9d732373\constraint-layout-solver-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.aar\cb0f3040d8654b9aee1823550cea3508\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\tw\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.aar\cb0f3040d8654b9aee1823550cea3508\res;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2 s.blubberme.engine.physics.Networks.ServerListenLoop
```

Comment: Upvoted, and ask some question: Do your Desktop-Java Code run in Desktop or in Android?

Comment: Desktop, no emulator needed

Answer (score 2):

I did this as follows:

Put all of the core code into a desktop project with a gradle build file.
Put the desktop stuff into another desktop project.
Put the android specific stuff into android studio.
Use the jar that the core project builds in each of the other projects.

An added bonus is that it makes unit testing the core code *very* easy.

See below for an example. The Android version had to set a callback.

```
interface Factory {
    Audio create();
    class FactoryImpl implements Factory {
        private FactoryImpl() {}
        @Override public Audio create() {
            return isAndroid()?new AndroidAudio():new WindowsAudio();
        }
        public static class AndroidAudio implements Audio {
            AndroidAudio() {}
            @Override public void play(Sound sound) {
                if(Audio.Instance.sound) if(consumer!=null) consumer.accept(sound);
                else l.severe("callback is not set: "+sound);
            }
            public void setCallback(Consumer<Sound> consumer) {
                this.consumer=consumer;
            }
            public Consumer<Sound> consumer;
        }
        private static class WindowsAudio implements Audio {
            WindowsAudio() {}
            @Override public void play(final Sound sound) {
                if(Audio.Instance.sound) try {
                    String filename=sound.name()+".wav";
                    l.info("play: "+filename);
                    Clip clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
                    AudioInputStream inputStream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(Audio.class.getResourceAsStream(filename)));
                    if(inputStream!=null) {
                        clip.open(inputStream);
                        FloatControl gainControl=(FloatControl)clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
                        gainControl.setValue(-25.0f); // ?
                        clip.start();
                        // maybe do not wait?
                        while(clip.getMicrosecondLength()!=clip.getMicrosecondPosition())
                            Thread.sleep(1); // wait
                        // or at least don't wait here?
                        //Thread.sleep(500);
                        clip.close();
                    } else l.warning("input stream is null!");
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    l.severe("caught: "+e);
                    l.severe("failed to play: "+sound);
                }
            }
        }
    } }
```

Comment: hi, ty I know this might be a valid solution, but I want to avoid it since I had to rewrite a lot of code then. I have some code like " void dosomething(){ if(isdesktop) { dosomething} else if(android) {dosomething else}"  so the desktop-code requires the android libraries at least as stub

Comment: you may need to jump through some hoops, but it's worth it. see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In *Java* (*Android Studio 3.4.1*), it's enough to include in any source `.class` file the `main` static method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello World! ");
   // your code
}
```

I program in *Kotlin*. *Kotlin* is fully interoperable with *Java*.  In this context, 
it's similar. One includes in some source `.kt` file the `main` function:

```
fun main()  {
   println("Hello World")
   // your code
}
```

In both cases it will appear a `green triangle icon` in the left of main function

[image]

So one can run the main function code in desktop (no emulator or cell phone) clicking the `green triangle icon`. It appears the options, including debugging. *Shortcut*: `Ctrl +Shift + F10`

The `green triangle icon` and the `green bug icon` in the top toolbar also allow in the left, select the right module (that has main function inside) and run instead of `app` (with `green ET head icon`). *Shortcut*: `Shift+F10`

[image]